# Cron job asking for hour

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cron

```
logFile="/home/..."

if [ `date +"%H"` == "14" ]
then
    echo "case1" >> "$logFile"
else
    echo "case2" >> "$logFile"
fi
```

This script is saved in a file and executed each hour as cron job. What I don't understand is that it always executes case2. If I execute it manually then it actually executes case1 when the current hour is 14. Why doesn't it behave like that as cron job and what can I do about it?

**EDIT:** I was asked to show the line which defines the cron job. I enter `crontab -e` in the shell to get there. The line is:

```
13 * * * * /home/path/to/my/script.sh
```

Comment: Please show the line in your `crontab` that executes this script.

Comment: have you evaluated the if condition yourself? If @ 14 run the if condition and have it print where it is. *You can always change 14 to whatever hour to test, so you don't have to wait

Comment: Yes, it seems that it should work as is, .... but it isn't. You need to add a line `echo current hour = $(date +"%H") > > "$logfile"` before the test so see what value is being returned for `date +%H`. You may need to specify `/path/to/workingcopyOf/date` . Good luck.

Comment: @lurker There is is...

Comment: I suspect your `.profile` sets your timezone, but the cron job is using the system timezone.

Comment: Show the very first line of your script (the 'shebang')

Comment: It's not a timezone problem. I let my script also print the time and the hour. It's the correct one.

Comment: @SeanBright My first line is the line where I specify the logFile.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain, you don't have a `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` as the first line?

Comment: @SeanBright Currently not.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain, Then put `#!/bin/bash` as the first line and test again

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain: or remove one `=`.

Comment: @SeanBright Thank you, putting `#!/bin/bash` in the first line solved the problem! I don't understand why but it works now as cron job and manually.

Comment: Because `cron` uses `sh` by default which is probably not `bash` on your system.